My phantom wallet shows different value of my tokens than my wallet regarding the solscan
i have a question, i will appreciate it if you can help me and of course if you know anything about it, the amount of tokens that i own (ski mask dog) if you go to my solscan its showing the exact amount of the the tokens that shows in my phantom wallet as well, but the value is different, in phantom wallet is like 1.5k less.
Why is this happening, and what can i do about it.?

This is a chronic problem where prices are not reflected properly, but Phantom Wallet has no intention of fixing it.
